# Semicolon in Content-Disposition filename

Tags: content-disposition

I have a problem trying to download filenames with a semicolon in them in IE8.

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + attachment.File.FileName + "\"");
```

Assuming that attachment.File.FileName = "Test;Test;Test.txt"

FF 3.5:  It prompts you to save/open the file with the name "Test;Test;Test.txt".  This is the desired result.

IE8:  It prompts you to save/open the file with the name "Test".

I need to figure out how to get the desired result in IE8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you made a test using the escape sequence for ; (%3B) ?

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"file%3Bfile%3B.txt\"");
```

Comment: That does indeed work for InternetExplorer but it's broken in browsers that follows RFCs (e.g. Firefox): percent-encoding is only allowed by RFC2231, but that does also required to use and star and two apexes: `filename*=utf-8'en'name%20with%20percent%20encoding`

Comment: That is IE-specific syntax. Don't.

Comment: The question is very clear: "To figure out how to get the desired result in IE8". As IE don't use the RFC, you have to include a specific patch to make this to work in that browser.

Answer (score -1):

check the condition for IE and use URLEncoder.encode. It will work.

Eg.:
`if (isIE) {
 fileName = URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8");
}`

Comment: No. Avoid special-casing UAs. It causes lots of harms in the long run (like unmaintained/untested code branches).

Comment: Unfortunately, Content Disposition filenames are not handled consistently in different browsers. Sniffing is unavoidable if you want to handle nonascii filenames.